# How to get place photos from this google place json in angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to retrieve the photos from google place. I can either assign to a scope variable or inject directly to my html.

Here is the json:

```
{
         "geometry":{
            "location":{
               "lat":-33.8666184,
               "lng":151.2027477
            },
            "viewport":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":-33.8665873,
                  "lng":151.2028499
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":-33.86671169999999,
                  "lng":151.2024411
               }
            }
         },
         "icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/lodging-71.png",
         "id":"111f458c4ee5ab8dd2658e0b442d4b14fda6b994",
         "name":"ibis Sydney King Street Wharf",
         "photos":[
            {
               "height":768,
               "html_attributions":[
                  "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109753793480552091881/photos\">ibis Sydney King Street Wharf</a>"
               ],
               "photo_reference":"CoQBcwAAAMBObG4lolSnWIAATUDUmPmFtQZmAOpop2ZtBwKDEakPVJfeNU6p8Uoh99Ur-bG4Y0INyg2lfqDp0YE5ClyiM7MbThMDRu-kc8JhQK4DtU47sY8zCycZ65cnQoVIXNHNxU52KrKdVrz9N60dTVFc1h1iptFRe329LnFcIQf_53szEhCTRSKy5Lg0NZFO0YjOZUigGhQ7JvvTi9_jYTtiAka8WODYJ5z7JQ",
               "width":1024
            }
         ],
         "place_id":"ChIJkzN9YUeuEmsRXS5xib231aQ",
         "rating":3.4,
         "reference":"CoQBcQAAANAhxbbcm_l3RznnFiPO4WDEKy78lA0_ZkyMONonsdWWTrygLz2dhctIKwt9hXFyy-y_413HvVYu5b3jHpdvmOjY3JDhZXGDmyB_7Ur_2Mw1aqmTilXTM7qEGoTRxyDGgVLbQ7k4NQl0NewBpc8rj6LASReVKMGwk46jXG4gxQ4YEhBdXNOpj-3cr_C10SwgHr4KGhStETM-GRqj79GgbEXy1y47dqMt9Q",
         "scope":"GOOGLE",
         "types":[
            "lodging",
            "restaurant",
            "food",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "vicinity":"22 Shelley Street, Sydney"
      }
```

For example..If I want to get the vicinity , I will usually just do a $scope.place.vicinity... but how do I get the photo or photos associated to the photos array?

Comment: what? `$scope.place.photos`? and then iterate over the array in an `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Are you asking me a question or suggesting I do an ng-repeat?

Comment: loop over the array. DO you know how to do loops in Angular?

Comment: @epascarello any example will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#example